# I have monthly data which I split up by all months for each year, how do I rebuild the data set to get back to normal, monthly data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter

I have monthly data which I split up by all months by each year, so each month (january, feb, etc.) has 25 points (25 years worth of monthly data).
The reason why I split up the data set per month is because I wanted to detrend each month separately.
Now the issue I have now is how do I rebuild the data set to get back to normal, monthly data?

Just to clarify, the monthly data set is split up in January, Febuary, March etc. with 25 points of all the Januaries for each year (25 total years).

This is my function to split the months up:

```
def split_months(monthly_data):
    month_split = []
    for month in range(12):
        month_split.append(monthly_data[month::12])
    month_split = np.array(month_split)
    return month_split
```

The function applied to my time series is:

```
lsds = split_months(ob_monthly(fwf_tot_grnl,26,28))
print(lsds.shape)

(12, 25)
```

The original time series is basically this exact array of values (each number representing monthly means):

```
data = np.array(
[  4.44        3.614       4.0460005   5.1229997   8.181001   23.88
  48.895      26.740002    7.454       9.884       5.093       4.2770004
   3.8999999   4.9040003   3.736       4.4030004  22.261      40.200005
  62.825005   47.         20.904001   10.974       5.723       4.5070004
   4.04        3.5040002   3.7760003   8.803      19.691      25.249998
  64.494995   44.36        8.723998    5.4339995   4.6829996   4.1770005
   3.8999999   3.4340003   3.726      11.383001   19.711      39.320004
  81.924995   44.109993   15.584       6.5639997   9.043       5.3770003
   4.9         5.644       5.426       9.943001   22.291      30.459997
  45.245003   30.32       15.934       5.694       5.873       4.597
   4.6400003   3.654       3.9460003   8.813      21.901      46.29
  54.90499    33.729996   14.974       7.3840003   5.9030004   5.0770006
   4.4700007   3.764       4.586      10.782999   19.921      59.17
  77.784996   41.09       13.904       5.244       4.183       4.077
   4.596       5.039       4.853      10.633999   11.36       25.538
  66.06901    60.221       9.421       5.9580007   7.3010006   5.1370006
   9.871       5.959001    6.2910004  11.011      15.582      41.586002
  61.489      62.522      22.592005    8.76        7.284001    6.6680017
   6.3420005   5.6429996   6.397001   13.169999   15.686999   35.1
  69.087      61.676994   16.506002    8.993002    9.748       9.421001
   7.5270014   6.089       6.802001    7.0059996  25.265001   52.129
  71.71501    37.315002   23.323002    8.122001    6.8900003   6.7650013
   7.5070014   5.7620006   6.369001    9.704      16.115002   61.615997
  78.908      75.03501    24.828001   18.709       8.946001    7.6440015
   7.036001    8.021001    6.745001    8.9609995  25.263998   53.342
  66.784      60.457996   12.041001    8.851002    7.6539993   7.332002
   8.109002    9.958001   10.364       9.103999   25.901      49.302998
  77.47001    47.663006   17.101002    9.033002   12.889999    8.370002
   7.4340014   6.643001    8.225       8.264002   27.967001   30.463001
  71.04099    66.920006   15.218003   10.14        7.986001    7.931002
  11.101       6.612001    7.8220005   8.818002   15.4159975  57.508
  95.218994   76.62101    15.224001    9.743       9.98        7.506002
   7.056001    6.377001    8.582001   11.452001   26.950003   48.557995
  80.06599    46.355      13.2630005  13.066001   10.836       8.853002
   7.9060006   6.7550006   7.1250005   8.478      18.976002   39.144997
  74.204994   46.373      10.978003    8.085002    7.340002    7.4710016
   8.144002    6.551       7.689001   11.208      36.002      66.902
 102.02799    82.63899    26.937      11.016       9.987       8.977001
   8.089001    6.610002    7.6930013   7.0730014  16.036      50.027996
 103.17498    66.486      13.222001    8.791002    8.938003    7.6330013
   7.270001    7.9689994   9.035001   15.478998   25.383999   85.61101
 131.645      70.778      19.850004   15.265      12.019999    9.633
   8.530001    7.2450004   9.307002   11.766      11.969999   38.693996
  69.27799    44.055004   14.650001   11.418       9.868003    8.571002
   8.055       7.061002    7.7850013   7.9510007  21.322002   45.706993
  87.51201    66.734      16.962       9.555001    8.364002    8.183001
   7.443001    7.8109994   6.9640007   6.980001   14.530002   38.425
  78.09       38.747      18.515001   10.052002    8.556001    7.909002
   7.576001    6.868001    7.470001   17.761002   23.598999   55.842
 100.045      65.67799    10.5130005   7.649001    7.543002    6.8360014])
```

Then you can apply my function split_months(data) to split the data into separate months like January (25 values), February (25 values) etc.

How do I go back to monthly data after splitting each month separately? Basically how would I return to the original data array (called data)?

Comment: Could you give us some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: yes of course! I just printed my array of the monthly data, then you can split each month by using my month_split function. and then the issue now is getting back to monthly data instead of all the data being split into januaries, febs, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would apply a nested loop in which the data gets stored like this: First value first row, first value second row,... first value last row. Then second value first row etc... This returns your original data. I defined it as a function as well:

```
def merge_months(split_data):
    merged_months = []
    for value in range(len(split_data[0])):
        for month in range(len(split_data)):
            merged_months.append(split_data[month][value])
    return merged_months
```

Is that what you're looking for? Note that this only works if all months have an equal amount of data points. Otherwise you need to change `len(split_data[0])):` in the first line of the nested loop.

Comment: yes yes!!! thank you. I will accept your answer and give you an upvote. This is exactly what I was looking for.